# How to extract an array from a matrix in GAMS?

Tags: gams-math

i'm trying to extract an array from a matrix in GAMS. For example, i want an array that is just one column (or one row) of the matrix. Is possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Of course.

```
Sets 
   i /i1*i100/
   j /j1*j100/
;
parameter a(i,j);
a(i,j) = uniform(0,1);
parameter u(i);
u(i) = a(i,'j25');
parameter v(j);
v(j) = a('i37',j);
```